# How Switch User And Backup A DataBase In MySql With Current User(Logged In User)?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i am using phpmyadmin for connecting to mysql.
my current user have some limitations for viewing all databases.
also i can not change the current user of phpmyadmin and login with admin user because i am in cpanel.
i have administrator user name and password.
which sql query should i use for switch to admin user and backup databases that that user can see?
also how can i download that sql file to my local machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';
```

Comment: @Nikola K. thanks for the answer. how can i figure out which user i am using?

Comment: why this code has error-> mysqldump -h localhost -u Username_ -pPassword_ DBName_> myDB.sql

Comment: also i test your codes in your answer and i got this error -> "#1142 - UPDATE command denied to user 'OurName'@'localhost' for table 'user'"